# awk if statement with simple math

Tags: unix, awk, gawk

I'm just trying to do some basic calculations on a CSV file.

Data:

```
31590,Foo,70
28327,Bar,291
25155,Baz,583
24179,Food,694
28670,Spaz,67
22190,bawk,4431
29584,alfred,142
27698,brian,379
24372,peter,22
25064,weinberger,8
```

Here's my simple awk script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN { FPAT="([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; OFS=","; OFMT="%.2f"; }
    NR > 1
END { if ($3>1336) $4=$3*0.03; if ($3<1336) $4=$3*0.05;}1**
```

**Wrong output:**

```
31590,Foo,70
28327,Bar,291
28327,Bar,291
25155,Baz,583
25155,Baz,583
24179,Food,694
24179,Food,694
28670,Spaz,67
28670,Spaz,67
22190,bawk,4431
22190,bawk,4431
29584,alfred,142
29584,alfred,142
27698,brian,379
27698,brian,379
24372,peter,22
24372,peter,22
25064,weinberger,8
25064,weinberger,8
```

**Excepted output:**

```
31590,Foo,70,3.5
28327,Bar,291,14.55
25155,Baz,583,29.15
24179,Food,694,34.7
28670,Spaz,67,3.35
22190,bawk,4431,132.93
29584,alfred,142,7.1
27698,brian,379,18.95
24372,peter,22,1.1
25064,weinberger,8,.04
```

Simple math is if
field $3 > 1336 = $3*.03 and results in field $4
field $3 < 1336 = $3*.05 and results in field $4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to force awk to recompile every record (by assigning to $4), just print the current record followed by the result of your calculation:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","; OFMT="%.2f"} {print $0, $3*($3>1336?0.03:0.05)}' file
```

Comment: And it knows to print results to fourth field because of $0?

Comment: If you have a large file you'll find it runs significantly faster than any solution that assigns to $4 before printing.

Comment: How do you handle subtraction without getting negative numbers? In field $4 results are less than 20 so I need 20 - $4 but its negative in $5: `{print $0, $4-($4>20?$4:20)}`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have anything in the END block

```
BEGIN {
    FS = OFS = ","
    OFMT="%.2f"
}
{
    if ($3 > 1336) 
        $4 = $3 * 0.03
    else 
        $4 = $3 * 0.05        
    print
}
```

This results in

```
31590,Foo,70,3.5
28327,Bar,291,14.55
25155,Baz,583,29.15
24179,Food,694,34.7
28670,Spaz,67,3.35
22190,bawk,4431,132.93
29584,alfred,142,7.1
27698,brian,379,18.95
24372,peter,22,1.1
25064,weinberger,8,0.4
```

Comment: I see, I was missing a couple { and the entire else statement.

Comment: Actually you weren't missing any braces I think I just added them out of habit. They aren't necessary if the code after the if statement is just one line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{if ($3>1336) $4=$3*0.03; else $4=$3*0.05;} 1' data
31590,Foo,70,3.5
28327,Bar,291,14.55
25155,Baz,583,29.15
24179,Food,694,34.7
28670,Spaz,67,3.35
22190,bawk,4431,132.93
29584,alfred,142,7.1
27698,brian,379,18.95
24372,peter,22,1.1
25064,weinberger,8,0.4
```

#### Discussion

The `END` block is not executed at the end of each line but at the end of the whole file.   Consequently, it is not helpful here.

The original code has two free standing conditions, `NR>1` and `1`.  The default action for each is to print the line.  That is why, in the "wrong output," all lines after the first were doubled in the output.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '$3>1336?$4=$3*.03:$4=$3*.05' file
```

The `conditional-expression ? action1 : action2 ;` is the much shorter terinary operator in awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk '$4 = (2 * ((_ = .01 * $3) < 13.36) + 3)*_' FS=, OFS=,
```

---

```
31590,Foo,70,3.5
28327,Bar,291,14.55
25155,Baz,583,29.15
24179,Food,694,34.7
28670,Spaz,67,3.35
22190,bawk,4431,132.93
29584,alfred,142,7.1
27698,brian,379,18.95
24372,peter,22,1.1
25064,weinberger,8,0.4
```