# using awk for subtraction

Tags: awk, gawk

Similar post here:
[awk if statement with simple math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768420/awk-if-statement-with-simple-math/)

Below is great but now I need to subtract 20 from field $4 if it's less than 20 and if its greater than 20, field five can be set to 0.

```
31590,Foo,70,3.5
28327,Bar,291,14.55
25155,Baz,583,29.15
24179,Food,694,34.7
28670,Spaz,67,3.35
22190,bawk,4431,132.93
29584,alfred,142,7.1
27698,brian,379,18.95
24372,peter,22,1.1
25064,weinberger,8,.04
```

I had something similar to this working but there's some errors with it now.

`{print $0, $4-($4>20?$4:20)}`

Because field $4 could be less than 20, I'm not sure the above will actually wok as I really want 20 - $4 not $4 - 20.

This gives me $4-20: `{print $0, $4-($4<20?20:$4)}` but I need 20-4 if $4 is less than 20. If $4>20 field $5 is 0.

Comment: There's only 3 fields in your file

Comment: Do you want 20 - $4 or $4 - 20, your post seems to contradict itself

Comment: This gives me $4-20: `{print $0, $4-($4<20?20:$4)}` but I need 20-4 if $4 is less than 20. If $4>20 field $5 is 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need is

```
{print $0, 20 - ($4 < 20 ? $4 : 20)}
```

Or to make it even more straightforward

```
{print $0, ($4 < 20 ? 20 - $4 : 0)}
```

If $4 is less than 20, this returns 20 - $4 as the fifth field.

If $4 is greater than or equal to 20, this returns 0 as the fifth field.

Comment: That was too simple! I had though g/awk would require the field outside the parentheses to register the field so I never tried 20-! Thanks so much.

Comment: Awk doesn't need anything to "register the field", it just evaluates the expression and prints it out, similar to most programming languages.